# Flutter | How to create arounded image?

Tags: flutter, crop, flutter-image

I'm trying to find a solution for resizing an image.
The images are picked from a gallery or camera. The problem that I have Is that the image always is not sharp.

This Is How I pick the photo

```
 void _showPickOptionsDialog(BuildContext context, UserData userData) {
    final user = Provider.of<Userforid>(context, listen: false);
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Pick From Gallery"),
              onTap: () {
                _loadPicker(ImageSource.gallery, userData);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Pick from Camera"),
              onTap: () {
                _loadPicker(ImageSource.camera, userData);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Future _loadPicker(ImageSource source, UserData userData) async {
    final XFile file =
        await picker.pickImage(source: source, imageQuality: 100);
    if (this.mounted) {
      // This checks if the widget is still in the tree

      setState(() {
        if (file != null) {
          _cropImage(file, userData);
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      });
      //Navigator.pop(context);

    }
  }

  _cropImage(XFile picked, UserData userData) async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      sourcePath: picked.path,
      aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio5x4
      ],
      maxWidth: 800,
    );
    if (cropped != null) {
      setState(() {
        _pickedImage = cropped;
      });
    }
    if (_pickedImage != null) {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('user_profile_pictures')
          .child(user + '.jpg');
      await ref.putFile(_pickedImage);
      final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      _curenturl = url;
      await DatbaseService(uid: user).updateUserData(
      ...);
    }
  }
```

And this is how I display them

```
Container(
                                            child: ClipRRect(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(60),
                                              child: Container(
                                                  height: 110,
                                                  width: 110,
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                  ),
                                                  child: _pickedImage != null
                                                      ? Image.file(
                                                          _pickedImage,
                                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                        )
                                                      : userData.url != null &&
                                                              userData.url !=
                                                                  "profilepictureer"
                                                          ? Image.network(
                                                              userData.url,
                                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                            )
                                                          : Image.asset(
                                                              'assets/profilepictureer.png') // Your widget is here when image is no available.
                                                  ),
                                            ),
                                            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                border: new Border.all(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                    width: 1)),
                                          ),
```

So the images are set as user profile photos. Probably a solution will be to upload rounded images like Instagram. So the question that I have is how can a user picks a normal photo from camera or gallery and upload it as rounded?
If not how to solve ghe problem then?

Comment: "upload rounde images like instagram". I'm pretty sure they don't round it before uploading

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap the widget with a ClipOval with flutter.

Take a look at this doc: [Flutter Document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html)

or Try using BoxFit.fill

```
child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        child: Image.network(
            userData.url,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
```

Comment: I use now ClipOval instead of ClipRRect its still round as before but the image is not sharp